# JSF Primefaces autoComplete list of suggestions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                    <h3>Search</h3>
                    <p:selectOneButton id="searchType" value="#{bean.searchType}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="search selected" />
                    </p:selectOneButton>

                    <p:autoComplete id="search" forceSelection="true" dropdown="true" value="#{bean.selectedSearch}" completeMethod="#{bean.search}">
                    </p:autoComplete>
                    <p:spacer />

                    <h:outputText value="Selected:" />
                    <h:outputText id="selected" value="#{bean.searchType}" style="font-weight: bold" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

I want to change the list of suggestions depending of which **selectOneButton** is pressed, but **autoComplete** only shows the list of suggestion that was selected when the page is loaded.

bean completeMethod

```
private int searchType;
private ArrayList<String> auditoryNumberList;
private ArrayList<String> lectureNameList;
private ArrayList<String> groupNameList;
private String selectedSearch;
public ArrayList<String> search(String q) throws SQLException {
        switch (searchType) {
            case 1:
                if (groupNameList == null) {
                    groupNameList = model.getGroupNameList();
                    return model.search(groupNameList, q);
                } else {
                    return model.search(groupNameList, q);
                }
            case 2:
                if (lectureNameList == null) {
                    lectureNameList = model.getLectureNameList();
                    return model.search(lectureNameList, q);
                } else {
                    return model.search(lectureNameList, q);
                }
            case 3:
                if (auditoryNumberList == null) {
                    auditoryNumberList = model.getAuditoryNumberList();
                    return model.search(auditoryNumberList, q);
                } else {
                    return model.search(auditoryNumberList, q);
                }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: solved by adding @ApplicationScoped

Comment: That is **no** solution... This means the bean is shared with all users. I doubt you want that. Create an [mcve] with all imports in it. Most likely the wrong package was used

Comment: Yes, I should use other scope.